# Large scale enterprise angular application split into Micro Front End Apps and deploy independently

Tags: javascript, angular

I have angular application with 5 modules (A, B, C, D and E) and some shared resources(services, directives and CSS). Now I have to split these 5 modules into 5 Micro Front End apps. Each Micro app should load dynamically when page url changes (micro app '**A**' should load when url is 'localhost:4200/**A**/pages' and micro app **B** should when url is localhost:4200/**B**/pages) and complete load (Page reload) should not happen when url changes from localhost:4200/**A**/pages to localhost:4200/**B**/pages.

**Precisely I want to split my angulaar app into 5 micro front end apps and there are minimal shared resourses between these micro apps. I should able deploy these micro apps independently**

I am having trouble with figuring out what is the best approach for achieving this, I seen all sort of articles but I still cant see a clear path.

Comment: Angular module lazy loading should help you : https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules. Or are you looking for some methodology/organization?

Comment: If you are using modules, then I assume you are already using lazy loading, if not, that will help you

Comment: It honestly sounds to me like you have it pretty much figured out. I worked on a team that used one repo shared between 3 teams, but we only worked on one feature module. It becomes a different question is you want separate repos though, so changes can be deployed independently.

Comment: @DanOswalt: Different repos and should be deployed independently

Comment: One pattern is a Shared directory, and a Features directory. Shared gets resources that more than one feature can access. Features has each module, lazy loaded via Router. Teamwise, you have to be clear on who and how shared/global things code is updated if five teams can be affected. Obviously don't want it touched a lot, but also you don't want 5 teams all developing utility service that should have been done once and shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know in Micro Frontend Architecture every micro frontend app should work independently from frontend to backend (i.e. your should have micro service architecture at backend or can have kind of BFF layer GraphQL to achieve vertical slicing of work).

**All micro frontend app you can develop as a node module.** serve all this module from private artifactory like JFrog or anything.

you can create a **UI Stitching layer** (layout layer) to integrate all the module as per your requirement you mention above.

You should avoid direct communication between all the micro frontend so in order to achieve that you can create a **Event Bus** (i.e. custom events) to setup communication between each micro frontend (like sharing of user preferences between all micro front end).

You can follow this micro frontend architecture to achieve your goal.

follow this [link](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html?utm_source=arador.com), this is really nice article.

Comment: Helpful information.

Working on the solution, will update here once I completed.